# XML serialization IOexception was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlserializer

i have the following code used to serialize a label's content. When i press the "save" button, an xml file is generated. When press the "load" button after i select the same xml file, an error occured, IOexception was unhandled, The process cannot access the file 'C:\datasaved.xml' because it is being used by another process. Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks.

```
public class FormSaving
    {
        private string major;

        public string Majorversion
        {
            get;

            set;

        }
    }



    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string savepath;
        SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
        // Default file extension
        DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
        // Available file extensions
        DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        // Adds a extension if the user does not
        DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
        // Restores the selected directory, next time
        DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
        // Dialog title
        DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
        // Startup directory
        DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
        DialogSave.ShowDialog();
        savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
        DialogSave.Dispose();
        DialogSave = null;

        FormSaving abc = new FormSaving();
        abc.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
        FileStream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
        serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
    }

    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Stream checkStream = null;
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog DialogLoad = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        DialogLoad.Multiselect = false;
        DialogLoad.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if ((bool)DialogLoad.ShowDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                if ((checkStream = DialogLoad.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    loadpath = DialogLoad.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");
        }

        FormSaving abc;
        FileStream loadstream = new FileStream(loadpath, FileMode.Open);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
        abc = (FormSaving)serializer.Deserialize(loadstream);
        loadstream.Close();
        MajorversionresultLabel.Content = abc.Majorversion;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most immediate problem:

```
FileStream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
```

You're not closing the stream, so the file can't be reopened for read. Use a `using` statement:

```
using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
    serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
}
```

You should take the same approach when *loading* the file as well, instead of calling `Close` explicitly... with your current code, if an exception occurs when deserializing, you won't be closing the stream.

You're *also* opening the file via `Dialog.OpenFile`, but not closing that stream... and why bother opening it twice? Just read from the stream you've opened.

Finally (for the moment) you're catching an exception (blindly, with no regard for *which* exceptions are really worth trying to handle) but then continuing regardless. If you've caught an exception, chances are the last part of the method won't execute correctly, so you should *either* return *or* throw another exception yourself.

Comment: hello jon skeet, thanks for you reply. after using the 'using' statements for both the save and load, i still have the same problem. Regarding the opening stream twice.. i was wondering if it will work i just have a single stream? let's say user loads an xml file that is edited manually. EDIT, sorry i am very confused now

Comment: @jeremychan: If the user currently has the file open in another process, it may well fail, yes. Is that the case for you here?

Comment: sorry i am totally confused now..what should i do? i don't have very good understanding of streams

Comment: @jeremychan: Well your situation is still unclear, but I've suggested a number of improvements to the code. I *would* definitely only open the stream once when you try to read; it's just possible that that's causing the problem (although the previous save bug was a definite issue too). But you're talking about the user having a file open elsewhere... is that *actually* the case, or not?

Comment: @jonskeet it is just one of the possible case but it should not happen. but what is the correct syntax if i just want to use savestream only? do i need to put in FileMode.Open as a parameter?

Comment: @jeremychan: Personally I use `File.OpenRead` as a simpler way of opening the file for read, and `File.OpenWrite` for writing. But as I say, you should also get rid of the extra stream. If you're still having problems after fixing all these issues, please edit the question with your new, cleaner code.

Comment: hi jon skeet, i finally understood what u were hinting at. I needed to close the checkstream which i didnt and now it worked